# App or website showing cheap business class flights?

Tags: luxury, business-class

Does anyone know a **free** website or app that is posting cheap business class flights?
I've found many websites, but they are only posting cheap economy class fares.
This page is the only one I know so far, https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/premium-fare-deals-740/, it's not bad, but the overview isn't the best.

I live in Europe, I know how to use flight search engines but they don't help to find offers. For economy flights for example I can look here https://www.urlaubspiraten.de/fluge . I am looking similar like this but for business class flights.

Comment: Flights to anywhere? From anywhere? Flight search engines (Kayak, ITA Matrix/Google Flights) allow you to specify the cabin you prefer and therefore to find the cheapest business class option for a given itinerary.

Answer (score 4):

Flyertalk is a good starting point and they often have the most "artistic" hacks.

Other good ones:

- https://www.premium-flights.com/
- https://www.premiumcabindeals.com/
- https://luxuryflightclub.com/

Comment: The first one Premium-Flights has an app as well. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For Australian and NZ-based deals, I post on my site [Beat That Flight](https://beatthatflight.com.au/), including business class deals when they arise.